# Python/SQLAlchemy: Connecting to a MySQL instance with Cleartext Authentication enabled

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'd like to access a MySQL server which is setup in a way that only allows mysql_clear_password. I am able to connect to using command like, with the --enable-cleartext-plugin option, like so:

```
>> mysql --port NNN -u my_user -h DB.host.com --enable-cleartext-plugin -D my_database
```

However, from Python (specifically using SQLAlchemy/PyMySQL) It doesn't seem possible to use the enable-cleartext-plugin  option. How can we optionally pass this information via Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there's no need to do anything special, and it has worked for me. When connecting to the DB, the server asks the client to use the plugin `mysql_clear_password`, and PyMySQL [already understands how to handle that](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/v0.9.2/pymysql/connections.py#L898).